# Switch video from webcam while stream live

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I try to switch 2 video from webcam with 1 audio file looped, every 30 seconds (f.e.), but i didn't find how ....

/dev/video0
/dev/video2

to broadcast the result on youtube (rtmp) via an RPi 3+

Someone can help me ? or lightup for a way ... ?

Comment: Yes many thanks llogan, just one extra question : can you explain how add a third input (image png for example) ?

Comment: What should the image do? Simple overlay?

Comment: Not overlay,  brodcast a static image and can be change to display the new one

Comment: More clearly, i wish to broadcated a static image updated each minutes
with ffmpeg -i image.png after 30" i encounte an error

av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipeB time=00:00:06.06 bitrate=4854.5kbits/s speed=0.0448x
    Last message repeated 1 times
[flv @ 0x966740] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x966740] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
Error writing trailer of rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/7gea-b563-947u-jqy1-8hz4: Broken pipe

Comment: Need to see your command and the complete log to be able to help.

Comment: llogan, i'd understand one things, if i use a jpg file its ok but worst with png, can you help me for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483613/brodcast-png-video-ffmpeg-with-raspberry?noredirect=1 ?

Answer (score 0):

### Switch webcams every 30 seconds and live stream

Use the [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) with [`enable` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) using [`lt` and `mod` functions](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation):

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -i /dev/video2 -stream_loop -1 -re -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=enable='lt(mod(t,60),30)'[v]" -map "[v]" -map 2:a -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 8000k -g 50 -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://youtube
```